# Prove 2 identical uniform's are independent by computing the joint distribution

Tags: probability, references, conditional-probability, independence, joint-distribution

Let $A,B,C$ be iid Unif(0,1). Let $X,Y$ be random variables:

- $X=(A-B)1_{A-B>0}+(1+(A-B))1_{A-B<0}$
- $Y=(C-B)1_{C-B>0}+(1+(C-B))1_{C-B<0}$

I am able to show that $X,Y$ are id Unif(0,1). My problem is showing they are iid (i.e. I'm missing the independent).

(I'm not allowed to use measure theory here, but I actually don't see how I would anyway since both $X$ and $Y$ have a '$B$' in the formula.)

Okay so elementary probability stuff only. Let's compute joint cdf and hope it's uniform on unit square. This is

$$P(X \le x, Y \le y) = 1_{x,y > 1} + x1_{0 < x < 1, y > 1} + y1_{0 < y < 1, x > 1} + xy1_{0 < x,y < 1}$$

I believe I get everything except the $xy1_{0 < x,y < 1}$ part.

It seems we have to take cases

- Case 1:$ X=A-B, Y=C-B$
- Case 2: $X=(A-B)+1, Y=C-B$
- Case 3: $X=A-B, Y=(C-B)+1$
- Case 4: $X=(A-B)+1, Y=(C-B)+1$

Okay let's try Case 1. (**Update: The bounds are wrong**, but the questions in re the tags are still valid, I believe.)

$$P(0 < X = A - B \le x, 0 < Y = C - B \le y)$$

What I think is conditional probability but of 2 random variables conditioned on 1. Instead of the usual $$P(z_1 < Z < z_2 | B=b) := \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f_{Z|B=b}(z) dz,$$ with $f_{Z|B=b}(z)=\frac{f_{Z,B}(z,b)}{f_B(b)},$ it looks like we'll have like $$P(z_1 < Z < z_2, u_1 < U < u_2 | B=b) := \int_{u_1}^{u_2} \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f_{(Z,U)|B=b}(z,u) dz du,$$ with $f_{(Z,U)|B=b}(z,u) = $, I think, $\frac{f_{Z,U,B}(z,b,u)}{f_B(b)}$

- Note: if any of the definitions ':=' are in fact *not* definitions, then you'll have to explain conditioning on an event of probability zero to me please.

So here's what I think is next:

$$P(0 < X = A - B \le x, 0 < Y = C - B \le y) = P(B < A \le x+B, B < C \le y+B)$$

$$ = \int_{b=0}^{b=1} P(B < A \le x+B, B < C \le y+B | B=b) f_B(b) db \tag{1?}$$

$$ = \int_{b=0}^{b=1} P(b < A \le x+b, b < C \le y+b | B=b) f_B(b) db \tag{2????}$$

$$ = \int_{b=0}^{b=1} \int_{b}^{x+b} \int_{b}^{y+b} f_{(A,C)|B=b}(a,c) dc da f_B(b) db \tag{3 part 1?}$$

$$ = \int_{b=0}^{b=1} \int_{b}^{x+b} \int_{b}^{y+b} \frac{f_{(A,C,B)}(a,c,b)}{f_B(b)} dc da f_B(b) db \tag{3 part 2?}$$

$$ \text{[details omitted because actually the bounds are wrong]}$$

$$ \text{[details omitted because actually the bounds are wrong]}$$

$$ \text{[details omitted because actually the bounds are wrong]}$$

$$ = xy $$

And then assuming all of the above is correct and all the question mark parts are justified, repeat for the other 3 cases and it looks like we have $xy$ in each. Are these cases supposed to be added up and so I'm missing $\frac14$? Or what?

- Case 2: $b-1<A<x+b-1, b<C<y+b$, so again just $xy$
- Case 3: $b<A<x+b, b-1<C<y+b-1$, so again just $xy$
- Case 4: $b-1<A<x+b-1, b-1<C<y+b-1$, so again just $xy$

About the question marks:

- For $(1?)$, I think the rule is like for an event $E$ and continuous random variable $B$, we have $P(E)=\int_{\mathbb R} P(E|B=b) f_B(b) db$. Is this correct?

  - Oh wait a minute [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero) says we can't quite do this. What I understand is that we can't do it for arbitrary $E$, but we can do it when (but not only when I guess) $E=\{Y \in \ \text{some interval or Borel set I guess}\}$, for some continuous random variable $Y$ s.t. the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}$ is well-defined? (I forgot if any 2 continuous random variables necessarily have a well-defined joint pdf.)
- For $(2????)$, I think we're doing something like for events $E$, $H$ and $G$ and continuous random variable $B$: we have $P(E|H)=P(E \cap H|H)$, but $P(G|H)$ is defined only for $P(H)>0$. What is being done here when technically $P(H)=0$? I mean of course in the 1st place when we say like '$P(E|B=b)$', this is notational, we're not really conditioning on the $P$-null event $\{B=b\}$. But I still don't get exactly what's being done here.
- For $(3 \ \text{parts 1 and 2})$, I'm actually just guessing here, **what's the definition of conditional joint cdf of 2 random variables given a 3rd? And please provide a reference**.

  - [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#Conditional_independence_of_random_variables) just says $F_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(x,y):=P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z)$, but it doesn't quite define $P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z)$.
  - For just 1 continuous random variable conditioned on 1 continuous random variable, it's $P(X \le x, |Z=z) := \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_{X|Z=z}(t) dt$, where $f_{X|Z=z}(t) := \frac{f_{(X,Z)}(x,z)}{f_{Z}(z)}$.
  - For 2 continuous random variables conditioned on 1 continuous random variable, I think it's $P(X \le x, Y \le y|Z=z) := \int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u) du dt$, but then...
  - What's $f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u)$? (I guess we do the elementary probability way of thinking: define the pdf before the cdf...) According to [this site](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_3_0_chapter_problems.php) (see problems 1 and 16), it's $f_{(X,Y)|Z=z}(t,u): = \frac{f_{(X,Y,Z)}(t,u,z)}{f_Z(z)}$. So, I guess I'm right about joint cdf/pdf stuff. I'm just hoping for a reference please.

Comment: As I wrote in an answer to a previous question like this one: **draw a picture.**

Comment: @Xi'an Although certainly your diagrams qualify, I don't see any 3D versions there.

Comment: @whuber wait I made a huge error over something apparently so simple (maybe). Please see edit. Is it correct? I have $xy$ now instead of $xy \pm$ (other stuff)

Comment: @whuber updated question. it's not just about the bounds now. i get the bounds are wrong. i figured out the bounds on my own. now i'm wondering about the joint pdf/cdf stuff mainly.

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4066689/321264.

Answer (score 8):

The joint distribution of $(A^-,C^ -)=(A-B,C-B)$ is given by its density
\begin{align}
f(a^-,c^-)&=\int f_A(a^-+b)f_C(c^-+b)f_B(b)\,\text d b\\
&=\int_0^1 \mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-+b)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-+b)\,\text d b\\
&=[\min(1,1-a^-,1-c^-)-\max(0,-a^-,-c^-)]^+\\
&=\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-a^-,1-c^-)-\max(0,-a^-,-c^-)]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-a^-,1-c^-)-\max(0,-a^-,-c^-)]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-a^-,1-c^-)-\max(0,-a^-,-c^-)]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-a^-,1-c^-)-\max(0,-a^-,-c^-)]^+\\
&=\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[\min(1-a^-,1-c^-)-0]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-c^-)+a^-]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[\min(1,1-a^-)+c^-]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[1+\min(a^-,c^-)]\\
&=\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[1-\max(a^-,c^-)]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)[1-c^-+a^-]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[1-a^-+c^-]^+\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)[1+\min(a^-,c^-)]\\
&=\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{a^->c^-}[1-a^-]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{a^-<c^-}[1-c^-]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{c⁻-a^-<1}[1-c^-+a^-]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{a^--c⁻<1}[1-a^-+c^-]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{a^-<c^-}[1+a^-]\\
&\ +\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(a^-)\mathbb I_{(-1,0)}(c^-)\mathbb I_{a^->c^-}[1+c^-]\\
\end{align}

The joint density thus writes differently on the 8 rectangular triangles of the $(-1,1)^2$ square as drawn below (with two triangles where it is null):

[image]

If one now considers $(X,Y)$ i.e.
$$X=A^-+\mathbb I_{A^-<0}\qquad Y=C^-+\mathbb I_{C^-<0}$$
its distribution is defined by the probabilities of arbitrary squares
$$\mathbb P((X,Y) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])
\qquad 0< x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2<1$$
which are equal to
\begin{align}&\mathbb P((A^-,C^-) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-+1,C^-) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-,C^-+1) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-+1,C^-+1) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&=\mathbb P((A^-,C^-) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-,C^-) \in [x_1-1,x_2-1]\times[y_1,y_2])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-,C^-) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1-1,y_2-1])\\
&\quad+\mathbb P((A^-,C^-) \in [x_1-1,x_2-1]\times[y_1-1,y_2-1])
\end{align}

Using the symmetries between the four translated squares, as in the figure below (feel free to move the squares!), the non-constant terms just cancel each other and one ends up with the uniform distribution on $(0,1)^2$.

[image]

---

A much faster resolution goes as follows: since $A^-$ and $C^-$ are independent given $B=b$
\begin{align}
&P((X,Y)\in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]|B=b)\\
&=\mathbb P((A^-+\mathbb I_{A^-<0},C^-+\mathbb I_{C^-<0}) \in [x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]|B=b)\\
&=\mathbb P(A^-+\mathbb I_{A^-<0}\in [x_1,x_2]|B=b)\times
\mathbb P(C^-+\mathbb I_{C^-<0}\in [y_1,y_2]|B=b)\\
&=\mathbb P(A-b+\mathbb I_{A<b} \in [x_1,x_2]|B=b)\times
\mathbb P(C-b+\mathbb I_{C<b}\in [y_1,y_2]|B=b)\\
&=\left\{\mathbb P(A-b \in [x_1,x_2]\cap[0,1-b]|B=b)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+
\mathbb P(A-b+1 \in [x_1,x_2]\cap[1-b,1]|B=b)\right\}\\
&\quad\times
\left\{\mathbb P(C-b \in [y_1,y_2]\cap[0,1-b]|B=b)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+
\mathbb P(C-b+1 \in [y_1,y_2]\cap[1-b,1]|B=b)\right\}\\
&=(x_2-x_2)(y_2-y_1)
\end{align}
the conditional joint distribution is Uniform, hence the marginal is also Uniform.

Comment: oh wow. thanks Xi'an. had no idea this would be so complicated. 1 - am i going somewhere with my thought 1? 2 - do you definitely disagree that $A-B$ and $C-B$ are independent for any independent $A,B,C$? 3 - Are $A-B$ and $C-B$ something 'conditionally' independent on $B$ for any independent $A,B,C$? (I didn't learn that much conditional independence in grad or undergrad.)

Comment: Thanks xi'an 1 - am i going somewhere with my thought 1?

Comment: Xi'an, 4 - wait so i'm going somewhere in my thought 3 re 'promote' (and thought 1 too perhaps)? i'd think to say joint cdf conditional on $B$ is uniform and then say the unconditional joint cdf is uniform

Comment: (damn it xi'an i accidentally deleted a comment aside from just -5 and -6...) Edit: (Oh good thing i had another tab open. the other comment i deleted was the update about the $xy$ thingy)

Comment: 7 - thanks xi'an! updated question. it's not just about the bounds now. i get the bounds are wrong. i figured out the bounds on my own. now i'm wondering about the joint pdf/cdf stuff mainly. may you please help with the joint pdf/cdf stuff and other stuff in the tag question marks parts?

Comment: 8 - actually it's more than just $\min\{1,(x/y)+b\}$ right? I believe there's also supposed to be $\max\{0,1-b\}$. i mean at least that's what i did in my computations. like each of the 4 cases are subject to 4 sub-cases and then among those 16 sub-cases i had '$\max\{0,1-b\}$' there

Answer (score 6):

**I would like the share the results of staring at a diagram.**  I promise to do almost no calculation (and the calculations that are performed involve only multiplications by $0,$ $1,$ and $-1$ along with additions).

Start by re-expressing $X$ as

$$X = A-B \mod 1,$$

which is just the fractional part of $A-B.$  This function is defined on the entire $(A,B)$ plane, where its contours look like those in the first figure.

[image: Figure 1]

On this figure I have outlined the unit square.  This is a [*fundamental domain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) for the group of unit translations of the square in the plane.  The group has other fundamental domains, though, such as this one:

[image: Figure 2]

These domains differ by two congruent regions in which the variables $A\mod 1,$ $B \mod 1,$ and $A-B \mod 1$ have matching values:

[image: Figure 3]

Therefore *the distributions of $A-B \mod 1$ are the same on both domains.*

However, there's an area (=probability)-preserving map between the domains.  The linear transformation defined by the matrix

$$\pmatrix{1 & -1\\0 & 1}$$

is a *skew transformation* that tilts the second domain (the parallelogram) sideways back into the first domain (the unit square).  Because it is a one-to-one area-preserving transformation and does not change the values of $A \mod 1$ or $B \mod 1,$ it does not change their distribution.  But the image of $A-B \mod 1$ under this transformation is just $A:$

[image: Figure 4]

We may perform a similar set of operations in the $(C,B)$ plane where $Y=C-B\mod 1,$ and achieve a comparable result.  The conclusion?  The combined transformation

$$\pmatrix{1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} = \pmatrix{1 & -1 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1}$$

is a one-to-one distribution-preserving transformation that maps $(X,B,Y)$ into $(A,B,C).$  Since the latter is a set of *iid* uniform$(0,1)$ variables, so is the former.  In particular,

> **$X$ and $Y$ have uniform distributions on $[0,1)$ and are independent (as well as being independent of $B$).**

As a check, here's a scatterplot matrix based on 1,000 realizations of $(A,B,C).$

```
A <- seq(0,1, length.out=11)[-1]
X <- expand.grid(A=A, B=A, C=A) + runif(length(A)^3*3, A[1]-A[2], 0)
X$X <- with(X, (A-B) %% 1)
X$Y <- with(X, (C-B) %% 1)
pairs(subset(X, select=c(X,B,Y)), pch=19, col="#00000010")
```

[image: Figure 5]

All bivariate marginal distributions, at least, appear to be uniform on the square, supporting these results.

Answer (score 5):

> I am able to show that $X,Y$ are id Unif(0,1). My problem is showing they are iid (i.e. I'm missing the independent).

Intuitively:

Besides $X \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y \sim U(0,1)$ you can also show the independence from $B$ like $X|B \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y|B \sim U(0,1)$.

- $B$ is the only common variable in the equations for $X$ and $Y$
- The distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are independent from this $B$

This leads to

- the $X$ and $Y$ are also independent from each other.

---

I believe that this intuitive view is sufficient. The rest, computing a joint distribution, is more like an awkward exercise that obscures the insight.

You could compute the joint distribution conditional on $B$ as a 2D uniform variable $X,Y|B \sim U(0,1) \times U(0,1)$ to show independence of the joint distribution from $B$ to conclude that also $X,Y \sim U(0,1) \times U(0,1)$

(I am using the symbol $\times$ to indicate the product of the pdf's, I do not know if there's an official notation or standard)

Comment: +1 This is by far the best answer.

Comment: @JarleTufto Xian also sort of gives the same answer at the end of his post (but it is obscured by lots of lines of formulae and that's why I added my short post).

Comment: Thanks Sextus Empiricus! 2 follow-up questions: 1 - is the the $X,Y|B \sim$ stuff below the line supposed to be the precise version of the intuitive stuff above the line? or is it an alternative prooff? 2 - in re the $X,Y|B \sim$ stuff below the line, my next question then is what exactly is conditional joint distribution of 2 (or more) random variables on a single random variable (at least assuming they all have continuous pdfs). I ask about this [here on maths se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4074248) and sort of [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515364)

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon **1** The stuff below the line is an alternative. It is how you can make the approach if you insist on using a joint distribution. **2** To make computations about this joint distribution easier, you could first compute the joint distribution of $X,Y$ with $B$ fixed to some particular value to gain intuition about the problem (particularly $B=0$ is easy and you could start with that, but for the intuition try others too), second do the same but consider it as a parameter. Third, you will realize that the value of the parameter $B$ does not influence the distribution of $X,Y$.

Comment: Another intuitive approach (but not necessarily easy) is that you could see the formula $f_B:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow [0,1]^2\,,\, f_B(X,Y) = A,C$ as a (injective) map/transformation of the points $A,C$ to $X,Y$ (and with $B$ a parameter that changes this mapping). A rule for computing the probability density of the transformed variable from the probability density of the non-transformed variable is using the derivatives (like $\frac{\partial X}{\partial A}$ and these are $1$ in your case, which makes that the probability density remains the same continuous function.

Comment: Link for the rule of pdf's of transforming variables https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables (this approach might be tricky because of the discontinuities and it is not using the rule with the condition that the function is monotonous, but you could say that it works as well if it is piecewise monotonous)

Comment: @Xi'an the second part of my answer is the same as your second part, but in the first part I give an argument that is different and simplifies the problem: there is no need to think about a joint distribution. I disagree with you that mathematical formulas can not be verbose and obscuring intuition, that doesn't mean I am against the use of formulas on this forum (But there are [differences](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5101) in styles). Personally I found the question post full of too much spaghetti, and that's what made me create this simple post. It was not criticism of your post.